# Kivy widget co-ordinates incorrect with collide_point

Tags: python, kivy

Obviously it's just me missing some knowledge here, but anyway, I'll ask my question.

I'm trying to make a circular touch-point on-screen, to simulate a joystick.  To implement this I'm starting with a circular-looking widget.  So I've drawn a circle in a widget, and have overridden the `Widget.collide_point()`.

However on testing: 
(a) my widget never uses the *bottom-right* location hint, and ... 
(b) seems to think it's centre-point position is off-screen.

I think this is some kind of issue with the Widget's co-ordinates not being finalised during construction (since I assume the container widget moves it), but I don't really understand how to progress this problem further.

[Aside] If I create the circle centered around `self.center_x` & `self.center_y`, it becomes partially off-screen to the lower left.  I don't get this at all.

I tried setting a call-back with clock to re-adjust the circle after the container-widget positioning was finalised, but that didn't help either.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Rotate, PushMatrix, PopMatrix, Line, Ellipse
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

import random

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = Window.size

class JoyStick( Widget ):

    def __init__( self, dial_width, **kwargs ):
        super( JoyStick, self ).__init__( **kwargs )
        self.radius     = dial_width // 2
        self.radius_sq  = self.radius * self.radius

        with self.canvas:
            Color( 200, 200, 20 )
            #Ellipse( pos=( self.center_x , self.center_y ), size=(self.radius * 2, self.radius * 2))
            Line( circle=( dial_width, dial_width, self.radius ) )

        self.size_hint  = ( None, None )  
        self.pos_hint   = { 'right':1, 'top':0 } 

    def collide_point( self, x, y ):
        centre_x = self.center_x
        centre_y = self.center_x
        print("JoyStick.collide_point( %d, %d ) -> cx=%d, cy=%d, r=%d" % ( x, y, centre_x, centre_y, self.radius ) )
        # Point-in-Circle Formula: if ((x-centre_x)^2 + (y - centre_y)^2 < radius^2) -> TRUE
        x_minus_cx = x - centre_x
        y_minus_cy = y - centre_y
        result = ( ( x_minus_cx * x_minus_cx ) + ( y_minus_cy * y_minus_cy ) < self.radius_sq ) 
        print("JoyStick.collide_point( %d, %d ) -> %s" % ( x, y, str( result ) ) )
        return result


class Screen( FloatLayout ):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super( Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Controller
        self.joystick = JoyStick( 150 )
        self.add_widget( self.joystick )

    def on_touch_down( self, touch ):
        if ( self.joystick.collide_point( *touch.pos ) ):
            print("Joystick Handled point")

    def update( self, dt ):
        pass


class MainApp( App ):
    def build( self ):
        screen = Screen()
        Clock.schedule_interval( screen.update, 1.0 / 60.0 )
        return screen



if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):    
    MainApp().run()
```

Stdout - in this case I had to stretch the window to actually have a 750x750 click.

```
JoyStick.collide_point( 531, 582 ) -> cx=750, cy=750, r=75
JoyStick.collide_point( 531, 582 ) -> False
JoyStick.collide_point( 672, 712 ) -> cx=750, cy=750, r=75
JoyStick.collide_point( 672, 712 ) -> False
JoyStick.collide_point( 737, 721 ) -> cx=750, cy=750, r=75
JoyStick.collide_point( 737, 721 ) -> True
Joystick Handled point
```

[image: main.png]

Answer (score 2):

Just a few suggestion for making this work. I would put the layouting in kv. And use `on_touch_move` instead. Well at least thats the way I would expect a joystick to work, On move.
Then there are some typos like `centre_y = self.center_x`
Well let me just throw the example here. It still looks kinda like what you are doing, just added some labels for debugging instead of printing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class JoyStick(Widget):
    radius = 70

    def collide_point( self, x, y ):
        result = (x-self.center_x) ** 2 + (y-self.center_y) ** 2 < self.radius ** 2
        return result

class MyLayout(FloatLayout):
    handling = StringProperty("")
    xt = StringProperty("")
    yt = StringProperty("")

    def on_touch_move( self, touch ):
        self.xt, self.yt = str(round(touch.pos[0])), str(round(touch.pos[1]))
        if ( self.js.collide_point( *touch.pos ) ):
            self.handling = "True"
        else:
            self.handling = "False"


KV = """

MyLayout:
    js: js
    JoyStick:
        id: js
        canvas:
            Line:
                circle: root.center_x, root.center_y, self.radius

    Label:
        font_size: "30sp"
        text: root.handling
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: "x: {}".format(root.xt)
        Label:
            text: "y: {}".format(root.yt)
"""


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


MyApp().run()
```